# How to edit text in a span or div through summernote field

Tags: javascript, html, css, summernote

I have two buttons one is Edit and Save. I have a div or span so onclick of edit button I want to convert the span or div in to a summernote editor and onclick Save it will save the data to same div and will remove the summernote editor.

I did not find any helpful information from summernote website, please suggest the right method.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summernote does provide a clear example to fullfil your needs, you may find it [here](https://summernote.org/examples/#click-to-edit).

```js
var edit = function() {
  $('.click2edit').summernote({focus: true});
};

var save = function() {
  var markup = $('.click2edit').summernote('code');
  $('.click2edit').summernote('destroy');
};
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script> 

<!-- include summernote css/js-->

<link href="https://summernote.org/vendors/summernote/dist/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="https://summernote.org/vendors/summernote/dist/summernote.js"></script>

<button id="edit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="edit()" type="button">Show Edit Mode</button>
<button id="save" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="save()" type="button">Hide Edit Mode</button>
<div class="click2edit">click2edit</div>
```

Comment: No you don't need it, i've removed codemirror references from the snippet

Answer (score 1):

When you click on Edit button, you can hide your div/span. With a jQuery code, it could be

```
<div id="summernote">/div>
<button id="edit-button">Edit</button>
<div id="editor"></div>
<button id="save-button">Save</button>

//JS
$('#edit-button').click(function() {
    $('#summernote').hide();
    $('#editor').show();
});
$('#save-button').click(function() {
    $('#summernote').show();
    $('#editor').hide();
});
```